# Discrete Mathematics Question - How many ways can you give 14 apples to your 8 favorite Mathematics lecturers if each of them gets at most two apples?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Very unsure as to how to solve this question. I know the solution involves the principle of inclusion and exclusion but the "at most 2 apples" part is very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Easy one: you give 2 apples to everybody, first. Then, you have to distribute the remaining -2 apples. You can give them to one of them, so that lecturer gets 0 apples in total (8 choices), or -1 to two lecturers, who get 1 apple in total, that's $\binom82=28$ choices. So there are $28+8=36$ ways to do that.

Comment: Oh thank you so much that makes a lot more sense than how my professor tried to explain it :)

Comment: Nice solution! I'll present the problem to my discrete math students :)

Comment: +1 I really like the formulation of this. Negative apples... I am inclined to believe now that they really exist.

Comment: it depends on how we interpret the keyword "favorite". A favorite lecturer should deserve at least one apple.

Answer (score 2):

The condition is $x_i\le 2$ for i from 1 to 8 with $x_i$ being the lecturer

$x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_8 = 14$ given the above condition.

Now put $y_i = 2-x_i$ then $y_i \ge 0$

Then $x_i = 2-y_i$

$2-y_1 + 2-y_2 +\cdots + 2-y_8 = 14$

$ y_1+y_2 +\cdots + y_8 = 2$

Then use stars and bars argument to find the solution of the above equation which is $${(2+8-1)\choose (8-1)} = {9\choose 7} = 36$$

Comment: The condition for the $x_i$ is $x_i\in\{0,1,2\}$. Also the condition for the $y_i$ is $y_i\in\{0,1,2\}$. Essential point is that this condition is *automatically*  satisfied if $y_1+\cdots+y_8=2$. Sometimes this trick works (like here), sometimes it doesn't.